# How to create nullable list in F#?

Tags: f#

I have a list of history entries that we retrieve from 3rd party software. This list can either be null or non empty.

In C# I would have written it like this, since list can be null:

```
List<HistoryEntry>
```

However I'm struggling in writing it in F#. I've already tried:

```
* Nullable<HistoryEntry list>
* HistoryEntry list option
* HistoryEntry list?
* HistoryEntry list | null
```

However none of this works. We use a ListConverter which is pretty much used everywhere, and I dare not change it (since that breaks everything):

```
type ListConverter() = 
    inherit JsonConverter()
    override __.CanConvert(t : Type) = (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<list<_>>)

    override __.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer) = 
        let list = value :?> System.Collections.IEnumerable |> Seq.cast
        serializer.Serialize(writer, list)

    override __.ReadJson(reader, t, _, serializer) = 
        let itemType = t.GetGenericArguments().[0]
        let collectionType = typedefof<IEnumerable<_>>.MakeGenericType(itemType)
        let collection = serializer.Deserialize(reader, collectionType) :?> IEnumerable<_>
        let listType = typedefof<list<_>>.MakeGenericType(itemType)
        let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases(listType)

        let rec make = 
            function 
            | [] -> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(cases.[0], [||])
            | head :: tail -> 
                FSharpValue.MakeUnion(cases.[1], 
                                      [| head
                                         (make tail) |])
        make (collection |> Seq.toList)
```

My question is: how to create nullable list that will be understood by this serializer?

Comment: Why don't you use the same list as you would use in C#?

Comment: The most F# idiomatic way is `Option<HistoryEntry> list` but I'm yet not sure if it satisfies this intimidating serializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think the problem is with the ListConverter, not the type of list you're trying to use.  The ListConverter does not account for the entire collection being null, which is perfectly possible in JSON.  I think the simplest change would be to use a custom version of `Seq.toList` that checks for nulls and converts them to an empty list.

```
let toJsonList s =
   if s |> box |> isNull
   then []
   else s |> Seq.toList
```

Then just change the last line of the ListConverter to be:

```
make (collection |> toJsonList)
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right, the converter didn't accomodated this and this will solve the problem. That should work without any side-effects, but I will keep testing it. Thanks!